# What is the best DB schema to handle exceptions and prevent redundancy?

Tags: mysql, laravel, optimization, database-design, polymorphic-associations

There are some products that can be sold in multiple units and the base unit is kilogram. The unit of each product has different weight, for example a Bundle of product A is 20kg but a Bundle of product B is 30kg

The following is my initial design.

```
product:
id       name

product_variation:
id    product_id      name        price

product_variation_unit:
id          product_variation_id             unit_id

product_variation_unit_weight:
product_variation_unit_id       weight
```

The problem is than most of the variation of a product have the same unit and weight. So here is my solution but I'm not sure it's a good idea:

```
selectable_unit:
id          selectable_id     selectable_type        unit_id
1            10               product                100
2            20               product_variation      101

selectable_unit_weight:
selectable_unit_id       weight
```

And when I want to get the unit and weight of a variation, first I will check the variation and if there isn't, I will check it's product.

I't a little complicated, can you help me to find a better solution or improve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the following diagram (Oracle Data Modeler notation). Usually, a price is depending on the SKU (stock keeping unit) and the period; a weight is depending on the SKU (packed product).
An SKU weight is limited by units allowed for its product (foreign key contains 2 columns).
`SKU.value` is the value in the unit to sell, i.e. kg, pcs, liters etc.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but the unit of each product has different weight, for example a Bundle of product A is 20kg but a Bundle of product B is 30kg

Comment: @Ali "A" is the product. A "Bundle of A" is the SQU. "Bundle of A" and "Bundle of B" have a weight. "Pack of C" may have a volume/length/pcs etc.